# Routing to another action than Index as default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I already searched for long, but for this case I found no answer.

I have a `HomeController` and the default route in my *route.config* is as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",  
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So; `http://localhost:36690/Home` automatically calls `Index`.

I also have a `MyController` (and it's custom route in *route.config*) with an `Index` method and can just write `http://localhost:36690/My` and it works.

But I want to have a custom route *without* any **`Index`**.

If I request `localhost:36690/New`, it should call `BASIC`.

So I tried the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "New",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "New", action = "Basic" }
);
```

But it ignores my default action 'Basic' and throws the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another route specifically for that controller.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "New",
    url: "New/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "New", action = "Basic" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

That way, when `/New` is called it will default to `NewController.Basic`

Comment: As you can see in the second code block in my question, I exactly did that. Unfortunately, it shows,,
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /New "

Comment: @thestruggleisreal Take another careful  look at the routes in my answer. Your second code block is different to what I suggested. By you having the same url template `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"` in both routes it will cause a route conflict. Also note the order I have the routes as that is also important. More specific/custom routes need to be added before more generic default routes.

Comment: I put it before default & tried {'New'}/{action} in the url (better if I'd mention that in the question, sry), & the url template of my ,New' route does not include id if this counts as a diff in the url template. But know I understand what you mean
My url:
    "{controller="New"}/{action}",
has to be
    "New/{action}",

No braces around the controller, thanks a lot.

Another question: in which case I need "{'New'}/{act}"? Or is it just a IDE weakness that it's accepted.
cause then, the Newroute wins the game always I go to localhost:xx/doesntmatter. That, in my eyes, is a bug

Comment: @thestruggleisreal the curly braces `{..}` are used for template parameters. The same way `id` was use as a parameter, if you had a parameter called `New` then you would include it in the template.